# Pandas transpose time (improve performance)

Tags: python, pandas, time, transpose

How can I reduce panda's time to transpose a huge matrix/dataframe?
I have a huge dataframe, I need to transpose it. But it takes to much time to do that. 
How can I do it faster? 
thx.

PD: I tried with df.T method.
Now, I am trying with array from numpy...however, it is too slow again.
PD: Original matrix (60k, 800)

Comment: Why do you need to transpose it?

Comment: Plot needs (however, I finished the process). but I would like to know other alternatives to get the same results in less time.

Comment: What do you need to plot? I don't see why it `needs` to be transposed? If it takes very long, may be better to figure out how to plot it given your rows.